# use of "here goes" in a sentence

Tags: verbs

Can we write "Here goes our findings from the factory visit" ?
Or, "Here goes all the files we had"?
Are these sentences correct? I'm confused because 'findings' and 'files' are plural, and we are using 'goes' after 'here'. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

[**Here goes!**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/here-goes) is a phrase used in particular circumstances - when you are about to do something new or daring. It is not appropriate to use it in an ordinary sentence; that would be *Here are our findings* (or the alternatives that Griffin suggests).

Comment: Thank you Kate! You've been very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I agree, this doesn't sound quite right. I would not use the word "go/goes" in this context. Instead, I would say one of these:

- In our factory visit, we found ...
- Our findings from the factory visit are as follows: ...
- Our findings from the factory visit are below: ...
- Here are our findings from the factory visit: ... (this is my least favorite because the phrase "are our" is hard to pronounce)

For the second example, I would say "here are the files we had" and use the verb "to be" instead of the verb "to go."

Comment: Thank you Griffin! You've been very helpful!